# Parse JSON without succession of Try-Catch blocks

Tags: java, android, json

I would like to parse a JSON, but every time I get a value, I have to put the instruction in a try-catch block. Here is an example:

```
try {
        this.setID(jsonObject.getLong("id"));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
    }
    try {
        this.setName(jsonObject.getString("name"));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
    }
//and so on....
```

I don't care if an instruction arise an exception. So I was wondering if it is possible to delete all the try-catch blocks and put the instructions all together.

Actually it is more a java problem and not only an android problem....

**EDIT**

Just clarifying what is the problem.
When an exception arises because there is not the tag I was looking for, I would continue with the next tag check instead of handling the exception. To do this, I have to write the code as I posted above, thus a succession of try-catch blocks. I was looking for a faster (and more elegant) solution.

Comment: Gson is a Java library that can be used to convert Java Objects into their JSON representation. It can also be used to convert a JSON string to an equivalent Java.

Reference: 
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html

Comment: A good code should have try-catch block handled properly rather that avoiding it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the `opt` methods instead of the `get` methods, assuming that it's okay for the keys not to exist. If the keys are not optional, and your app cannot recover from those fields not all existing, you should definitely use the `get` methods and fail fast if you run into an error.

Another helpful method you can use is the `has()` method. This checks if there is a mapping for a given key. (e.g. `if (json.has("id") id = json.optString("id"))`).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: Doc is here https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject#optString(java.lang.String) There also exists optString(name, fallback), optInt(name), optInt(name, fallback) and many others. Be sure to look, there are many interesting methods.

Comment: Is there any way to also avoid try/catch for `put` method? This `JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(); obj.put("a", 1);` can not be used without try/catch because put throws: https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject#put(java.lang.String,%20int)

Answer (score 9):

Maybe I didn't understand what you're asking, but why don't you put all calls to `jsonObject` within the same try-catch block?

```
try {
    this.setID(jsonObject.getLong("id"));
    this.setName(jsonObject.getString("name"));
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // log or consume it some other way
}
```

You should **never** just swallow exceptions. At least log an error.

Comment: You can also just use the `opt` methods instead of the `get` methods. These will return a default value if the value could not be retrieved, and do not throw an exception. This should, however, only be used if it's acceptable that a value not exist, otherwise you should definitely handle the exceptional case.

Comment: @Sotirios yes, but at the first exception it will stop parsing the json.

Comment: @kcoppock ok thanks! I didn't know about that function. If you put it as an answer I can accept it :)

Comment: @DanieleVitali It's an exception, you should handle it. Consider using what kcoppock proposed.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis if the op wants to know fetching which particular field (name or id) gave the exception, your answer of placing both fields in same try block wouldn't be of use would it?

Comment: @KewalShah In _code_ logic, no. But these libraries typically contain the name of the field in the exception's error message. For logging or debugging, it'll be available.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thanks I'm new to Android, didn't know that

Answer (score 1):

Like @Sotirios was saying you can't disregard a json exception.

You can put all your json reading in a method and make that method throw the JSONException, like this:

```
    public void readJson(String json) throws JSONException{
     this.setID(jsonObject.getLong("id"));
     this.setName(jsonObject.getString("name"));
   }
```

but you steel have to do a try catch when you call that method:

```
    try {
            readJson(jLine);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Maybe I was not clear. I meant, when an exception arises because there is not the tag I was looking for, I would continue with the next tag check instead of handling the exception. To do this, I have to write the code as I post above, but I would be a succession of try-catch block. I was looking for a faster (and more elegant) solution, as the @kcoppock's one. Hope it is better now :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is more of a library problem than anything else. A couple of JSON libraries in Java tend to add exceptions in their library calls as if the designer wanted to use invasive C-like error status codes but with the added weight of Java exceptions syntax. I can partially understand the motives for such an interface, but it looks really inelegant.

I would suggest using [json-simple](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/), which is too simple sometimes but gets the job done and stays out of the way.

Comment: I'm agree with your thinking. However using the opt methods it's a good (and elegant) alternative :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
jsonObject.getFoo("key")
```

with

```
jsonObject.optFoo("key")
```

If the key is not found, a `null` or similar default value is returned instead of an exception being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

If you want cleaner syntax, you should look at [gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). If you know what the json will look like, nothing beats it.

If your JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "id": 432942039,
    "name": "My name",
    "values": [0, 1, 2, 3]
}
```

You'd create a POJO class that looks like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    public MyClass() {}
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private int[] values;
}
```

And parse it like this:

```
private parse(String jsonString) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    MyClass myObject = gson.fromJson(jsonString, MyClass.class);
}
```

And that's it. No setters are needed; it uses reflection to match the fields. No annotations. No errors if there are fields in your JSON string that don't match anything in your POJO and vice versa.