# why is try catch required for every field in json parsing

Tags: java

I see an old method from a colleague of deserializing json object in java where the json is taken as string deserialized and passed the values in an array. What I dont understand about this code is why for every field try and catch method is added and why can't we have a single try and catch because all catch do the same thing of catching the json exception and assigning responseArray[0] to value 1. 
Here is the code:

```
String[] responseArray = new String[4];
            Arrays.fill(responseArray, "");
            try {


                final JSONObject response1 = new JSONObject(response);

                try{
                    responseArray[0] = response1.getJSONObject("body")
                        .getJSONObject("responseStatus").getString("estado");
                }
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    responseArray[0] = "1";
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if(!responseArray[0].equalsIgnoreCase("0")){
                try{
                    responseArray[1] = response1.getJSONObject("body")
                        .getJSONObject("responseStatus")
                        .getString("codigoRespuesta");
                }
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    responseArray[0] = "1";
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try{
                    responseArray[2] = response1.getJSONObject("body")
                        .getJSONObject("responseStatus")
                        .getString("descripcionRespuesta");
                }
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    responseArray[0] = "1";
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                }
                try{
                    responseArray[3] = response1.getJSONObject("body")
                        .getJSONObject("responseData").getLong("esValido")+"";
                }
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    responseArray[0] = "1";
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                responseArray[0] = "1";
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return responseArray;
```

Comment: I would steer clear of any code this colleague gives you in the future... this is like something from thedailywtf.com.

Comment: Hello,I found an answer on the post...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19231321/parse-json-without-succession-of-try-catch-blocks?rq=1

Answer (score -1):

There is no explicit need to add try and catch blocks to every ".getJSONObject" methods.
There are two ways by which you can use exception handling. 
1. try-catch blocks. Single try & catch block would work fine as well. 
2. Let the method *throws JSONException* as a replacement to try and catch blocks.

Checked exceptions (like the one in your case) are checked at compile time, and so you need to handle them using either of the two ways
Exception handling [reference link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/checked-vs-unchecked-exceptions-in-java/)